# Dispose of old variable used to construct useful value

Tags: c++, destroy, temporary

Assume the following two classes:

```
struct A {
    A()  {}
};

struct B {
    B(const A& a) {}
};
```

It happened to me multiple times to have a situation where I have to create a temporary instance of a class in order to build an instance of something I need to use. Something like:

```
A a;
// Do very complex computations using a;
B b(a);
// use b, a is not needed anymore.
return make_result(b);
```

My problem is that sometimes the resources held by `a` after my computations can be significant, and after I instantiate `b` I would like to release them. At the same time, the whole process `a -> b -> result` is logically a very compact thing and I would like to avoid splitting it into functions, since in such a case there would be [pretty much nothing to gain](http://number-none.com/blow/john_carmack_on_inlined_code.html).

What are available solutions in C++ to solve this type of problems?

Comment: I really don't understand what your problem is. If you need to keep the resources used by A for `result` to be meaningful, then keep them. If you don't, deallocate them, typically in A's destructor. All "available solutions in c++" are *that*: deallocate what you're not using.

Comment: Move `a` into `b`? `B b(std::move(a));`

Comment: `b` does not need to keep `a` usually, just to do something with its internals. The problem is that you cannot really call `a` destructor.. How would you do it? `a` usually does not get destroyed until the end of its scope.. and its scope must include the whole of `b`, since `b` can only be created using `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a default-constructed object to `A`, assuming that `A`'s assignment operator properly frees "resources":

```
A a;
// Do very complex computations using a;
B b(a);
a = {};
// use b, a is not needed anymore.
return make_result(b);
```

You could change `B` to take `A` by value and move the constructed `A` instance into `B`:

```
struct A {
    A()  {}
};

struct B {
    B(A a) {}
};
// ...
A a;
// Do very complex computations using a;
B b(std::move(a));
// use b, a is not needed anymore.
return make_result(b);
```

which has the nice advantage that `B`'s constructor can possibly "steal" resources from the `A` object.

You could use a lambda to construct the `A` and pass it to `B`:

```
B b([&]{
    A a;
    // Do very complex computations using a;
    return a;
}());
// use b, a is not needed anymore.
return make_result(b);
```

You could both construct the `A` with a lambda *and* have `B` take it by value:

```
struct A {
    A()  {}
};

struct B {
    B(A a) {}
};
// ...
B b([&]{
    A a;
    // Do very complex computations using a;
    return a;
}());
// use b, a is not needed anymore.
return make_result(b);
```

which allows `B` to steal things from `A` but doesn't leave a zombie `A` instance laying around.

Comment: I like the idea of the lambda to keep the code close, but using function semantics to ensure `a` gets deleted. It *does* look a bit weird though!

Comment: @Svalorzen You can also define the lambda at function scope and assign it to some `auto var_name` and call it after that.

Answer (score 0):

Largely it depends on the classes you have crafted in your program. Both `A` and `B` must be having common protocol (or sub-protocol to other class), and a common storage implying that protocol (e.g. a `vector` of some custom `struct`). If that is the case, the class having the responsibility can have function for *resource-delegation* (like `set_owner`), which another class can utilize. The pattern largely (or totally) depends on classes/resources/patterns you have.

If some common protocol exists, one or both (or multiple) classes may be changed appropriately.

If classes are similar (involving inheritance, or nested classes, for instance), then return-value-optimization, Name-RVO, or `move` constructs may be employed.